# default value not prefilling in input field when using ng-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am using ng-init to get some default values in my input fields. Its working properly. But when I add ng-autocomplete to the input field the default value is no longer showing in input field.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app=testApp>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="ngAutocomplete.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="searchCtrl" ng-init="roomsInit('london')">
                    <input type="text" ng-autocomplete ng-model="searchLocation" class="form-control input-lg"  options="locationFilter">
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
app = angular.module("testApp", ['ngAutocomplete']);

app.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.locationFilter = {
        country: 'uk',
        types: '(cities)'
    };    $scope.details2 = '';



    $scope.roomsInit = function (location) {
     $scope.searchLocation = location;

     //below code is not relevant to this case
        $http({
            url: "/search.json",
            method: "GET",
            params: {location: $scope.searchLocation,
                q: {
                    daily_price_gteq: $scope.min_price,
                    daily_price_lteq: $scope.max_price,
                    room_type_eq_any: [$scope.private, $scope.entire, $scope.shared]
                }
            },
            paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'
        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.rooms = response.rooms;

        });
    };

});
```

If I remove the ng-autocomplete it works fine.Could someone have a look
[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/43cOE29WRlOQXcTx7kDC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive you are using doesn't support ng-model and requires you to pass your model to ng-autocomplete:

```
<input type="text" ng-autocomplete="result" details="details" class="form-control input-lg"  options="locationFilter">
```

This runs the auto-complete when you type in the box.

I believe the directive you are after is this one: https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete/blob/master/src/ngAutocomplete.js

**UPDATE**
The directive you are using has a watch which clears the value after it runs the first time:

```
scope.$watch(scope.watchOptions, function () {
    initOpts()
    newAutocomplete()
    element[0].value = ''; // <-- This resets the value
    scope.ngAutocomplete = element.val();
}, true);
```

If you don't care about modifying the directive, change it to this:

```
scope.$watch(scope.watchOptions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        initOpts()
        newAutocomplete()
        element[0].value = '';
        scope.ngAutocomplete = element.val();
    }
}, true);
```

This stops it from wiping out the value unless you change the options/`locationFilter`.

Comment: Yes..but but how to make the initial ng-init value to load in the input field?  In the pluncker provided by ng-autocomplete.js they have mentioned like this aswell ng-autocomplete ng-model=""...

Comment: In the pluncker I provided in the question the autocomplete is working fine..But how to make the default value to work?

Comment: The default value does technically work, the directive you are using wipes out the value though. See my edit.

Comment: exactly mate..I got it fixed by getting getting autocomplete.js from their example implementation. But didnt know in which line this happens as I moved on ignoring it..Now its clear. Thank you for the explanation..